# Drupal adds unneeded folder to urls

Tags: uri

I've got the following problem:

We've got a hosting with 2 domains applied (second domain (the drupal site) is pointing to a subfolder of the first domain):
    /data/user/www/   < php-docroot & web-root of first domain
    /data/user/www/domain2/   < web-root of second domain & drupal install

calling http: //domain2.tld/ succesfully showing the drupal site,
but instead of:
http: //domain2.tld/content/contact, drupal generates url like:
http: //domain2.tld/domain2/content/contact

I think the problem may be the php-docroot, which is the same for domain1 and domain2.

How to tell Drupal to supress the /domain2/ part in urls?

Comment: It depends. What a contact is? A node? A page created by module? Are you using pathauto?

Comment: contact was only an example, drupal adds the /domain2/-part to ALL urls on the site, and yes i'm using pathauto (& clean-urls)

Comment: Weird. Is it added to all entries in the database? Or in the path entries in database it's OK but then on site it gets added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i noted above, drupal thinks it's installed in a sub-folder because of the php-docroot lies in the parent-folder of the drupal-install, so it added /domain2/ to the $base_url.

To fix it, just edit your current settings.php in sites/* folder:

$base_url = 'http://domain2.tld';  // NO trailing slash!

Make sure settings.php is writable, it's often read-only!
(this was the problem here, otherwise i would've saved a lot of time searching a alternative ways to fix the $base_url... looks like there's a overhaul needed in my svn:post_commit-ftp_upload-script ;)